# Clicking Shutdown shuts down immediately instead of showing dialog. Cannot restart

Tags: unity, 11.10, shutdown, restart, dialog

In Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric (Unity), clicking on shutdown will immediately shut down the machine instead of prompting with Restart / Shutdown option dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this myself in 11.10, but in previous versions it worked.

1. Run `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools` to install `dconf-editor`
2. Open up Configuration Editor (<kbd>ALT+F2</kbd>) `dconf-editor`
3. Go to apps > indicator-session
4. Make sure `suppress-logout-restart-shutdown` is unchecked.
5. Click shutdown from the cog menu.

Just tested this in 11.10 and it does work.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I was checking the option in gconf but not in dconf. Am a bit perplexed as to why options are scattered and duplicated over the two config systems. Otherwise I am now a happy user :)